# Testing for a significant increase in the frequency of periods of time where wind is blowing easterly for 5 days or more in a row

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out whether the number of instances where the wind direction (U) is blowing <(-3.54) for >=5 days in a row is increasing significantly over time at a 10% level. Below is the code I have used to produce the number of instances per year in Austral Summer. I have already checked for a significant increase using Excel at a 5% level, but I would like to learn how to do it using R and at a 10% level. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
####WIND PERIOD CALCULATIONS###########################################################################
#### U <(-3.54)
###Austral summer#######################################################################################
library(dplyr)

AusSum_Wind <- data.frame(year=character(), instances=integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
RowNum <- 1

for (i in 1993:2015) {
  AusSum_Wind[RowNum,1] <- paste(as.character(i), as.character(i+1), sep = "-")

  wind %>%
    filter((Month >= 10 & Year == i) | (Month <= 3 & Year == (i+1))) %>%
    mutate(threshold = U < (-3.54),
           group = cumsum(threshold != lag(threshold, default = FALSE))) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(n_days = n()) %>%
    summarise_all(first) %>%
    filter(threshold, n_days >= 5) %>%
    select(-group, -threshold) -> instances
  AusSum_Wind[RowNum,2] <- nrow(instances)

  RowNum <- RowNum + 1     
}

AusSum_Wind

> AusSum_Wind
        year instances
1  1993-1994         1
2  1994-1995         3
3  1995-1996         3
4  1996-1997         1
5  1997-1998         5
6  1998-1999         3
7  1999-2000         4
8  2000-2001         2
9  2001-2002         1
10 2002-2003         0
11 2003-2004         3
12 2004-2005         3
13 2005-2006         1
14 2006-2007         1
15 2007-2008         1
16 2008-2009         0
17 2009-2010         3
18 2010-2011         5
19 2011-2012         1
20 2012-2013         5
21 2013-2014         4
22 2014-2015         3
23 2015-2016         2
>
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.